# Ubuntu 15 is slower than 14

Tags: performance

Just installed Ubuntu 15. Completely deleted Ubuntu 14. However, running a 3GHz with 1 gigabyte of RAM, I'd think Ubuntu would 'fly'. Ubuntu 15 is much slower than Ubuntu 14 was and I wouldn't begin to know why. Any advice?

Comment: There is no such thing as Ubuntu 14 or Ubuntu 15. There is Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 14.10, Ubuntu 15.04, and Ubuntu 15.10. Please edit your question to show the proper version numbers.

Comment: Well yes, 15.04 is a little bit slower compared to 14.04, but the difference is not very noticeable

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu isn't typically very fast with only 1 GB of RAM. As time goes on, it will expect more and more RAM because it's designed for fairly recent computers, and 'fairly recent' changes as time goes on.

Some alternatives that can handle that much RAM much better are [Xubuntu](https://xubuntu.org/) and [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/).

They both are officially approved by Canonical (Ubuntu's manufacturer), work fine with all the applications available for Ubuntu, and have exactly the same `apt-get` and other typical terminal commands.

## Installing on an existing Ubuntu machine

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and type one or both of the following:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Then, you'd log out, choose to use either Xubuntu (XFCE) or Lubuntu (LXDE), and log in under it.

## Installing from scratch

If you want to install from scratch, make sure you get the 32-bit version of either. It will still work just fine on 64-bit systems, but it uses up even less RAM.